# How to remove rows based on responses to two columns

Tags: r

This is my first time posting here and I'm also an absolute novice with respect to r, so apologies in advance for any clear errors and ignorance on my part!

I have a large set of survey data (imported from excel), with the survey including two "attention check" questions. To be included in the data analysis, participants must have answered **both** of the attention check questions correctly. If they skipped or answered one of the questions incorrectly but answered the other correctly, they would still be included. The only participants I want to remove from the data are: those who skipped OR answered the first attention check question incorrectly AND skipped OR answered the second attention check question incorrectly.

For reference, when I click on the data in r studio it appears that r has automatically coded those who have skipped any of the questions as "NA".

The two attention check columns columns in the data are named "Attention.Check.1" and "Information.5". The correct response to Attention.Check.1 is "2" and the correct response to Information.5 is "5".

The only attempt I've made so far is below, and this was only an attempt to remove those who had missed both of the attention check questions entirely (note: ideally I would be able to also remove those who also provided incorrect answers to the two attention check questions).

`data <- data[!is.na(data$Attention.Check.1) | !is.na(data$Information_5),]`

However, when I apply the code above it only appears to remove the rows where there are missing responses to Attention.Check.1 (that is, there are still rows where the participant has given a blank response to Information.5). Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

| symbol means OR
& symbol means AND
Try:

```
data <- data[!is.na(data$Attention.Check.1) & !is.na(data$Information_5),]
```

if you want both answers to be present.

Comment: Thanks for this Arduan, that's really helpful!

But looking at the remaining participants after running that line of code, it seems to have removed more than it should have? Having a quick look, it seems like even those who provided a response to Attention.Check.1 but missed Information.5 were removed.